# Why do these variables NOT have to be final or effectively final?

Tags: java, java-8

Consider the following code:

```
static int k;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0; i++;
    new Thread( () -> {System.out.print(i); });      

    int[] j = new int[1]; j[0]++;
    new Thread( () -> {System.out.print(j[0]); });   

    k = 0; k++;
    new Thread( () -> {System.out.print(k); });      
}
```

In the first case, I get an error "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". I understand the rationale behind this error: the code inside the lambda expression might run at a different time where the value of i will be different so the results will be different than expected.

What I do not understand is: why do I not get the same error in the second and third examples, which are effectively identical?

EDIT: there are many questions about why the first case is an error. My question is different: I ask why the second and third cases are NOT considered errors?

Comment: If you fix the first error, does the expected second error show up? If yes, then probably the compiler's error detector is detecting all the errors and suppressing the ones that it thinks might be duplicates or otherwise noisy. The desired outcome is both "show all the relevant errors" and "don't overwhelm the user with noisy cascading errors"; since those are opposites, it can be hard to find an algorithm that achieves both ends.

Comment: But more generally: do you understand the scenario that the error is warning you about? Do you believe that this scenario applies to the second and third scenarios?  If so, how? If not, then you should not be surprised that there is no warning.

Comment: @EricLippert the second and third expected errors do not show even when I completely remove the first error.  As far as I understand, the problematic scenario is that the variable i might change by the main program before the inner code is executed; the same scenario might happen with j and k.

Comment: Captured variables (which include local variables, and `this`, which is effectively a local variable) must be final or effectively final.  The first example captures `int i`, which is not effectively final, so error.  The second captures `int[] j`, which _is_ effectively final (remember, final vars can refer to mutable objects).  The third captures nothing, because `k` is not a local.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this is not a duplicate. That question asks why the first case is an error. I ask a different question: why the second and third cases are NOT considered errors?

Comment: I think you don't understand the scenario that the error is intended to protect against; it's intended to protect against *closing over a mutable local*.  It's not intended to protect against *reading from or writing to a mutable variable*. Do you see why those are different things?

Comment: Let's approach it from a different direction. **Describe how you would design a rule that made the second and third cases into errors**. Can it be implemented at a reasonable cost? Does your rule make a large class of perfectly safe lambda expressions illegal?

Comment: @EricLippert to your first question: no, I do not understand why those are different things... can you refer me to an explanation?

Comment: third case is an error you just do not get to it, just because you do not understand why it **is a duplicate** does not make it not one. the accepted answer in the duplicate explains very clearly why this behavior exists and when it is applicable.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I understand the technical reason why the second and third cases are not errors, I just do not understand the rationale... the three cases are identical for all practical purposes, so why does the compiler treat them differently?

Comment: they are not identical, they are completely different, you not acknowledging the difference even though they have been explained multiple times.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi The lifetime of them is not the same. In the first case the local variable may disappear while the thread is living. In the second case, the array is an object and the thread captures a reference to it. In the third as it is a static then its lifetime is beyond the lifetime of the main invocation. You may construct another semantic for closures but that one is simple and reasonable.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks! Finally an answer I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

The second example doesn't give a compiler error because it satisfies the *effectively final* rule. the identifier `j` is never changed since it *always* refers to the same array, so you can access it within the lambda statement block. Performing the operation `j[0]++` is changing the state of the array *but* is not changing where `j` is pointing to in memory, thus completely acceptable.

The last example works because the variable `k` is a global variable which doesn't have to be *effectively final* nor *final*.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but I still do not understand *why* the last two cases are not considered errors? While they are technically different than the first case, they have exactly the same effect. In the third example, k is static.

Comment: I ask what is the rationale behind this rule?

Comment: the question you should be asking is why must local variables be "effectively final or final", but I don't get why you think the last two examples should give a compilation error. **if you can provide a good reason that it should error** then maybe we can go on from there...

Comment: Because the last two examples are effectively identical to the first one. Why does it matter whether I use a local int, or an int in an array, or a static int? it's the same int...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi in C# captured variables can be mutated regardless of whether it's local or global, an int, array of ints, static int whatever... and probably other languages as well which is where think you're getting to, hence why I said you should be asking why must local variables be "effectively final or final" not what you're asking currently as I can't get my head around that question.